# How to get correct device number for snd_rawmidi_open()?

Tags: c, linux, midi, alsa

Using `amidi -l` I get a few card results:

```
Dir Device    Name
IO  hw:2,0,0  CLASSIC ORGAN CMK3 CLASSIC ORGA
IO  hw:3,0,0  CLASSIC ORGAN CMK3 CLASSIC ORGA
IO  hw:4,0,0  CLASSIC ORGAN CMK3 CLASSIC ORGA
IO  hw:5,0,0  Wireless USB Midi Tranceiver MI
```

I am able to identify the wireless device through iterating through sound cards using `snd_card_next()`, and then comparing the names of the cards using `snd_card_get_longname()`.
But these return names, whereas `snd_rawmidi_open` needs a Device, i.e. `hw:5,0,0`. How can I iteratively determine the device number for the Wireless Transceiver, so I can use it for the `snd_rawmidi_open` function?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to simply collect the card index taken from `snd_card_next`, and turn it into an entry of the form `hw:card_index, 0, 0`, i.e.

```
sprintf(name, "hw:%d, 0,0", card_index);
```